# How to define custom axis in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I had the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(520)
y = np.random.rand(520)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

which produces the following graph:

[image]

How can I define a custom axis so my X-axis looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

- `plt.xscale('log')` to change the scale to a log scale
- [`set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/ticker_api.html) to set the formatting back to normal (replacing the `LogFormatter`)
- `set_minor_locator(NullLocator())` to remove the minor ticks (that were also set by the log scale)
- `set_major_locator(FixedLocator([...]` or `plt.xticks([...])` to set the desired ticks on the x-axis

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, NullLocator, FixedLocator
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(520)
y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 520).cumsum()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xscale('log')
# plt.xticks([...])
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator([2**i for i in range(0, 7)] + [130, 260, 510]))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(NullLocator())
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]